# Aspect Ratio with two rectangles

Tags: geometry, ratio

This is probably simpler that I'm making it (it would have to be), but I'm stuck and don't even quite know how to language this.

Imagine I have two boxes; one has a width of 3/4 of the whole, and the other is the remaining 4th.  They are side by side and initially have 0 height.

I fill box-1 (3/4) box with an object that is 100% wide and who's height is determined based on aspect ratio.  So box-1 stretches to the height of this object and keeps it same width.  Box-2 still has the same width (1/4th of the whole) and zero height.  Using aspect ratio I want to create an object that will fill box-2 and match the height of box-1, but I can't figure out how to calculate said aspect ratio.

Specifically - the aspect ratio of the item in box-1 is currently 4.5:1 and using trial and error I got the heights to match with ~1.6:1 in box-2; but I have no idea if that is reliable or if it will work consistently.

Any help?

A Drawing:
[image]

Comment: It would help a great deal if you drew a picture and labeled the various lengths with letters like $a,b,c,\ldots$.  The question as written is very difficult to understand.

Comment: I understand completely.  Hopefully the drawing helps.

Comment: According to your drawing, you need to set $y=1$.  Also, $4.5$ is three-quarters of 6, so you need to set $x=1.5$.

Comment: Although your answer was, in retrospect, hilariously obvious, it unfortunately isn't working in practice.  I think the reasons why may involve other variables that fall outside of the purview of this math problem.  The logic of your answer is what I was looking for though; so thank you.

Comment: My pleasure.  This was still a useful exercise, as it uncovered that the real issue is not the math but the "other variables".